# Can you change your crew after the heist is planned?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I just finished evaluating the jewelry I want to rob, as well as choosing my crew and how to rob the place. Now, I'm on my way to steal a Bugstars Pest Control van, when suddenly, Rickie Lukens, the programmer from Lifeinvader whom I helped with his pop-up virus problem, called me and asked me if I could get him a job.

Now since the heist is already planned, I was curious if I can't switch my current hacker with Rickie Lukens, after I evaluate his skill and the share he wants.

Is there a way to do this, and how?

Comment: About Rickie Lukens: In the long run, I believe it is better to take Rickie on this first heist (The Jewel Store Job) due to his low cut, and one of the gold medal objectives requiring the player to steal the jewelry within fifty seconds (Rickie's limit). He'll get better for future heists while still maintaining his low cut.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to change the crew once it's been selected, unless you have a game save before you made the selection that you can revert to. I was unable to change the crew when I tried.

Answer (score 2):

You can't change it unless you do the heist and then replay it

Comment: Do you then get the money for the heist on replay?